# How to speed up time when using Java Mail to save attachments?

Tags: performance, io, jakarta-mail

I separate *Message msg* into *Multipart multi1 = (Multipart) msg.getContent()*.
And a mail attachment is in one BodyPart, *Part part = multi1.getBodyPart(i);*
Then I want to save the attachment.

```
private void saveFile(String fileName, InputStream in) throws IOException {
File file = new File(fileName);
if (!file.exists()) {
  OutputStream out = null;
  try {
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    in = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFSIZE];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
      out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    LOG.error(e.toString());
  } finally {
    // close streams
    if (in != null) {
      in.close();
    }
    if (out != null) {
      out.close();
    }
  }
}
```

But it cost too much time on reading IO Stream. For example,a 2.7M file needs almost 160 seconds to save on the disk. I have already tried Channel and some other IO Stream, but nothing changed. Any solution for saving attachment using Java Mail?

For more code information https://github.com/cainzhong/java-mail-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/java/mail/impl/ReceiveMailImpl.java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, mail.imaps.partialfetch takes effect and speeds up a lot. There is a mistake for my previous code.

```
props.put("mail.imap.partialfetch","false");
props.put("mail.imap.fetchsize", "1048576"); 
props.put("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false"); 
props.put("mail.imaps.fetchsize", "1048576");
```

instead of

```
props.put("mail.imap.partialfetch",false);
props.put("mail.imap.fetchsize", "1048576"); 
props.put("mail.imaps.partialfetch", false); 
props.put("mail.imaps.fetchsize", "1048576");
```

It is important to put a quotation mark on "false". If not, the parameters will not take effects.

Anyway, thanks to Bill Shannon.

Comment: Hero. This has significantly improved speeds. 9mb file download from what feels like forever to like 4 seconds. And yes, set both imap and imaps.

Answer (score 1):

There's two key parts to this operation - reading the data from your mail server and writing the data to your filesystem.  Most likely it's the speed of the server and the network connection to the server that's controlling the overall speed of the operation.  You can try setting the [mail.imap.fetchsize](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.fetchsize) and [mail.imap.partialfetch](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.partialfetch) properties to see if that improves performance.

You can also try using something like [NullOutputStream](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/test/java/com/sun/mail/test/NullOutputStream.java) instead of FileOutputStream to measure only the speed of reading the data.

Comment: It seems improved. But just a little.
using props.put("mail.imap.partialfetch", false);
    props.put("mail.imaps.partialfetch", false);
    props.put("mail.imap.fetchsize", "1048576");

Comment: Make sure you're using the mail.imap.* or mail.imaps.* properties depending on which protocol name you're using in the getStore call.  If it doesn't get much faster then you're running into network or server speed limitations.

Comment: Hello, the URLs in your answer for `fetchsize` and `partialfetch` are now out of date.  Can you please update?

Comment: Done. (15 chars)